# Call function in the function

Tags: php, function

how to about my code i cant call function inline function

Here is my code:

```
function antus(){
   global $vidi;
   $vidi = random_int(100, 999);
}


function bntus(){
   global $hexa;
   antus();
   $hexa = 5 * $vidi;
   echo $hexa;
}

bntus();
```

Thank you

Comment: Learn about scoping of variables and stop using `global` like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "call function inline function"? There are no inline functions here, just named functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing return in both function and no need for global

```
function antus(){
$vidi = random_int(100, 999); 
return $vidi;
}


function bntus(){
$v = antus();
$hexa = 5 * $v;
return $hexa;
}

$a = bntus();

echo $a;
```

Comment: Just because the OP can't indent code doesn't mean you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

While it's poor style to use global variables instead of parameters and returns, I'll show you how you would do it.

You don't need `global $hexa`, since you never use that variable outside the function. But you need to put `global $vidi` in `bntus()` so that it can access that variable.

Also, the name of the function to get a random integer is `rand()`, not `random_int()`.

```
function antus(){
   global $vidi;
   $vidi = rand(100, 999);
}

function bntus(){
   global $vidi;
   antus();
   $hexa = 5 * $vidi;
   echo $hexa;
}

bntus();
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/bK3qBB)

Comment: okey thank you, now, i know i not use global for end code just use echo for show the finish string

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code doesn't run at all because it doesn't compile. The PHP statements end with `;` (but in your code it is missing in several places).

Properly formatted and without syntax errors, the code of function `bntus()` should look like this:

```
function bntus()
{
    global $hexa;
    antus();
    $hexa = 5 * $vidi;
    echo $hexa;
}
```

Now it runs but it doesn't produce the result you expect because the variable `$vidi` is not initialized.

If you think that the call to function `antus()` puts some random value in `$vidi` then you are wrong. The function `antus()` puts a value in the **global** variable `$vidi`. That variable is not accessible in function `bntus()`; it uses an uninitialized **local** variable with the same name.

Read about the [scope of variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP.

Declaring `$vidi` as `global` in function `bntus()` produces the expected results but using global variables is a very poor programming technique. It is out of fashion for about 40-50 years now because it makes the programs difficult to develop and maintain.

A better approach is to let the functions [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) the values they compute:

```
function antus()
{
    return random_int(100, 999);
}

function bntus()
{
    return 5 * antus();
}

echo(bntus());
```

One more thing: you didn't post the code of function `random_int()` but if it does what its name says then you don't need an user function for that. PHP already provides the [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function that, when is invoked with two integer arguments, returns a random integer number from the interval bounded by the two input values (including them).

This means the call `rand(100, 999)` returns a random integer number `$n`, `100` <= `$n` <= `999`.

Comment: wow, Short code just use return, i know function the return like a global but not use global, return is finish the function for call, Thank you i know this now

Comment: There isn't any relationship between `return` and global variables. The value returned by the function is the value of the function call. In the expression `5 * antus()`, the value of the `antus()` function call is the value `return`-ed by the body of the function. It is the value of `random_int(100, 999)` in this case. And the value of `random_int(100, 999)` is the value of the argument of the `return` statement from the body of `random_int()` that makes the function complete. A function can contain any number of `return` statements. The first one that is executes ends the function execution.